# Using Docker TensorFlow 1.13 with Newer GPU

Tags: docker, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a neural network (https://github.com/AiviaCommunity/3D-RCAN) written in version TensorFlow 1.13.1. I have an RTX A6000 GPU (running on Windows), which is not compatible with older versions of TensorFlow, and attempting to train the network on newer versions has introduced other complications. Would Docker provide a means of training the network on TensorFlow 1.13.1 with my RTX A6000? The project does not include a Dockerfile, but I've been able to train the network on my other computer (also Windows) with an older GPU and could try to create a Dockerfile myself if that's a potential solution.

Comment: If you can do tensorflow 1.15, nvidia has a docker that supports the newer RTX (not sure about A6000). I found this out myself when one of my company's GPU died and we got a 3070 only to find out it wasn't well supported with old tensorflow. Otherwise, you'll have to look into cloud or use an old GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've been trying different versions of tensorflow (1.13-1.15 so far). The GPU seems to be found, but keras is hanging in model.fit in every case. Do you happen to know which of the versions at [https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=1.15](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=1.15) your company used?

Comment: We had some extra complications, we couldn't go beyond Python 3.6 or else a library dependency wouldn't work, so I wouldn't recommend the exact container. That being said, you should get it from nvidia and not docker hub. https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow/tags